# Determine the operating voltage of a SIM card

Tags: voltage, sim

I'm trying to get my SmartCard reader to communicate with my phone's SIM card. I have a [level shifter](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCN4555-D.PDF) to drive 1.8V and 3.0V SIM cards, but the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module) specifies that there are also 5.0V SIM card. I just want to be sure that my SIM card is not a 5.0V one.

How can I determine the operating voltage of my SIM card? (I have access to a scope, and my SIM card is a Tesco Mobile one produced by Gemplus.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ETSI standard](http://www.etsi.org/WebSite/Standards/Standard.aspx) **ETSI TS 102 221** describes the procedure for switching (and thus finding the appropriate) supply voltage in section 6.2:

> **6.2 Supply voltage switching**
>   The terminal shall initially activate the UICC with the lowest voltage
>   class available. If no ATR is received, the UICC shall be deactivated
>   and activated with the next higher class, if supported by the
>   terminal. If an ATR is received at the first applied voltage class,
>   the contents of the ATR shall be analysed by the terminal. If the
>   operating class used by the terminal is not supported by the UICC, the
>   terminal shall deactivate the UICC and activate it with a supply
>   voltage class indicated by the UICC. If the ATR is corrupted, the
>   terminal shall perform the procedure at least 3 times using the same
>   operating class before rejecting the UICC. In case of 3 consecutive
>   corrupted ATRs, the terminal may activate the UICC with the next
>   higher class. The terminal is restricted not to use but the next
>   higher class in the retrial attempt in this case.